# Getting the error "TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html" when runnig a django project

Tags: python, django

I tried few of the solutions I found with no success.
Here is the urls.py file:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import include
admin.site.site_header = 'Marked By Covid Admin'


urlpatterns = [
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
]
```

The **TEMPLATES** part of **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client-app/dist')],

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Structure of the project:
[image]

Please let me know if anything else is needed.
I'd be grateful for your suggestions regarding what's wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Show template-related part of settings.py.

Comment: Maybe the project's hierarchical structure?

Comment: Show where do you keep `index.html` file. (it can be image of your file structure)

Answer (score 0):

This line in your settings tells Django where to look for templates:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client-app/dist')]
```

The basic Django's backend for it (that you are also using), checks for the template like:

```
YourProject/
  YourProject/
    <the directory you placed in 'DIRS'>
  your_app/
    <the directory you placed in 'DIRS'>
  your_second_app/
    <the directory you placed in 'DIRS'>
```

By default it's `'templates'` so it's simple. You have changed it to `'client-app/dist'`, so you can put index.html i.e. here:

```
YourProject/
  YourProject/
    client-app/
      dist/
        index.html
```

It has to be in an app (that is also in INSTALLED_APPS) or in project's core folder.

Comment: I moved the index.html file as you instructed, and added the application's name ('client-app') to INSTALLED-APPS. I guess I should be writing it differently because I'm getting another error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app label 'client-app' is not a valid Python identifier.`.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that it's possible to use dash in app's name, so it's not your app, so it's not possible to use it in INSTALLED_APPS. The best thing you can do is to name it back to `'templates'` and put it in `templates` folder inside any real app or project's core folder.

Answer (score 0):

i see:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # some staff
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'client-app/dist')],  # CLIENT-APP/DIST!
        # otherr staff
    }
]
```

But your `index.html` template you put in folder: `CLIENT-APP/PUBLIC`:
[image]

Are you really want to do it?

Comment: That's a finished project I was given, so it should be running as it is.